# VBA Line Input # doesn't work with TAB char inside line

Tags: vba, input, tabs, line

I want to read a text file into an array line by line. When the file contains a TAB character inside a line, this TAB character is completely ignored. => how to avoid TAB skipping easily?

Code basically looks like

```
Open strFilePath For Input As #1
arrIndex = 0

Do While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, my_row
    ReDim Preserve strArrLines(0 To arrIndex)
    strArrLines(arrIndex) = my_row
    arrIndex = arrIndex + 1
Loop
```

Reading the file line by line is a must, since the lines get filtered before they're put into the array (not shown in the code here, to show it as easy as possible).

Comment: Are you saying you need to handle TAB like a line break?

Comment: What are you seeing which makes you think the Tab is not being captured?

Comment: Tim raised the right question. Inside MS VBA the watches don't show TAB characters, though they are there. Even if I add a sequence of multiple TABs between two words, the watch shows just one word without any space in-between. Looks like a visualization issue inside MS VBA environment. Issue solved. Thanks for your help.